# What does #(nop) mean in docker history?

Tags: docker

What does the `#(nop)` prefix mean when listing `docker history`?

```
$ docker history swarm
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY   
c54bba046158        9 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) CMD ["--help"]
```

Comment: I would say "no operation". Can you post the relevant part of the Dockerfile?

Comment: Think @user2915097 is right. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP

Comment: It does likely mark the command as a no-op, but the question WHY this happens remains...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

NOP stands for "no operation".

Docker "runs a shell" for every layer. All the docker commands (or layers) in the Dockerfile except the `RUN` command show up in the history as empty or commented out shell commands. The `#` sign marks the start of the comment and anything after that will be skipped by the `/bin/sh`. Similarly if you typing in the terminal:

```
user@machine $ echo hello world
hello world
user@machine $ #But none of these lines starting with # do anything
user@machine $ #echo hello world
```

The non-`RUN` commands will not need to be interpreted by the shell, but instead are processed by docker internally.

The history (including the non-`RUN` commands) can be used by the layer cache to skip processing in case the same command has been run previously.

Comment: Took me awhile to understand this, but I take it to mean that the `docker history` command plays back a `/bin/sh` log record file, and docker commands like `ADD` and `CMD` that didn't need the shell to execute (presumably the work was done using some other tool) are echoed to the shell as comments so that they will still show up in the log record and thus the `docker history` command ..... I think.....

Answer (score 4):

```
FROM ruby:2.6-alpine
ENTRYPOINT ["sleep", "infinity"]
ENV A 1
```

```
$ docker build -t my-useless-image .
$ docher history --no-trunc my-useless-image
... CREATED BY                                         ...
... /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV A=1                         ...
... /bin/sh -c echo test                               ...
... /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENTRYPOINT ["sleep" "infinity"] ...
...
```

For `RUN` commands, it displays the shell command it executed, e.g.

```
/bin/sh -c echo test
```

For non-`RUN`, `/bin/sh -c #(nop)` followed by the `Dockefile` command that was performed in that layer. `/bin/sh -c #(nop)` doesn't really mean anything useful, and can be ignored. They made it look like a shell command, but it would fail if executed.

Comment: The real answer!! If I run the command `$ /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["--help"]`, I will get the error: `/bin/sh: 0: -c requires an argument`