# Docker - determining the actual default command for an image: what '/bin/sh -c #(nop) ENTRYPOINT ["xyz"]' mean?

Tags: docker

I am trying to figure out the exact command to be executed by default when I run the image as I know that it runs java and I'd like to add memory restrictions to this java command.

Both `docker inspect <image>` and `docker history <image>` show the following command for the topmost layer: `/bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENTRYPOINT ["./bin/run.sh"]`.

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44439088/1847482) and I understand from it that everything after '#' is ignored. 
Does it mean I should skip this layer and look for the first one without `#(nop)`? 
It does not make much sense for me as this is the only command I could find in `docker inspect` output.

**So, what is the actual command here?**

Answer (score 2):

The `docker history` command provides details about how the image was created, and what actions were performed for each layer of the image. The commented line in the history is in fact a "nop", where nothing was run to create that layer, and in fact you won't see a filesystem layer for that step. Instead, steps like ENTRYPOINT, CMD, ENV, LABEL, etc, modify the metadata associated with an image that you can see in the `docker image inspect` command.

For more details on how ENTRYPOINT and CMD are related and interact, see the [Dockerfile documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).

Comment: I also found that it may be helpful to pass the `--no-trunc` flag to `docker history [image name]` to see the whole command

Answer (score 0):

Found through experiments that the command is indeed "./bin/run.sh", it is just specified as ENTRYPOINT and not CMD in the Dockerfile.